# Knockout execute function after visible binding check

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list that is being rendered inside an foreach loop with knockout. I can remove items from the list, and for doind that, i'm using a "fadeOut" effect. I achieved this with this function binded to 'beforeRemove':

```
self.fade = function(elem) {
if (elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
  $(elem).fadeOut(function() {
    $(elem).remove();
  })
 }
}
```

I have a message that shows up if I don't have any itens on the list. The problem is that when I remove the last item, it starts to fadeOut, but the message shows up before the item is removed. How to show this message only after the last item is completely hidden?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/v2774x0f/

Comment: My best suggestion would be to fade in the message at the same rate at which the item fades out. It should look considerably more natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/v2774x0f/1/

There really isn't a graceful way to do this. You could add an additional property that gets set to prevent showing the message until all animations are complete but this is hacky at best

```
self.removing = ko.observable();
self.list.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue.length ===0) {
        self.removing(true);
        setTimeout(function () { self.removing(false); }, 500);
    }
});
```

Basically it's assuming the animation takes half a second to complete and preventing your message while removing is true and it was set to zero.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do custom bindingHandler, extending foreach, something like that (http://jsfiddle.net/v2774x0f/5/)

**JS**

```
o.bindingHandlers.myForeach = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        if (valueAccessor().data().length)
            $(valueAccessor().emptyElement).hide();
        ko.bindingHandlers['foreach']['init'].apply(null, arguments);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var args = arguments,$el = $(valueAccessor().emptyElement);
        if (!valueAccessor().data().length) {
            setTimeout(function() {
            $el.fadeIn();
            },500);
        } else {
            if (!$el.is(':visible'))
                ko.bindingHandlers['foreach']['update'].apply(null, args);
            else {
                $el.fadeOut(function() {
                    ko.bindingHandlers['foreach']['update'].apply(null, args);
                });
            }
        }

    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="myForeach: {data: list, beforeRemove: fade,emptyElement:'#listEmpty' }">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.remove">remove</button>

</div>
<div id='listEmpty'>
    You don't have any items
</div>
```

Comment: A binding handler is a good approach.  However, your fiddle doesn't appear to work.

Comment: This helped with my case, though I only needed: `ko.bindingHandlers.whenVisible = { update: function(e, v, b) { if (b.get('visible')) v()(); }` (minified for comment's sake).